# Ash Furrow's uicollectionview in uitableview example

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview

I do not quite understand why he needed an index parameter, or what it is used for, in his example:

http://ashfurrow.com/blog/putting-a-uicollectionview-in-a-uitableviewcell/

```
CGFloat horizontalOffset = scrollView.contentOffset.x;

UICollectionView *collectionView = (UICollectionView *)scrollView;
NSInteger index = collectionView.tag;
self.contentOffsetDictionary[[@(index) stringValue]] = @(horizontalOffset);
```

I also see people discussing the example. Can someone shed some light?

[Discussion that referred the Ash Furrow example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28125205/multiple-uicollectionviews-inside-a-uitabelview-with-sections-swift/28127622#28127622)

Answer (score 0):

The `index` is used as the key in the `contentOffsetDictionary`, used to store where the collection view was the last time it was on screen (it defaults to zero if it hasn't been on screen yet). That way if you scroll away from a cell with an embedded collection view, then back to it after the cell has been reused, the collection view is still where you left it.

Comment: Thanks Ash! Didn't think of scroll view position when the cell is reused...good thought. When a collection view cell is reused, does it have different z value in the view debugger in Xcode? I see different z values of some cells...really weird.