# Different UICollectionViews in UITableView objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uicollectionview, nsindexpath

I have 2 custom UITableViewCells in my TableView wich are using a UICollectionView. How can I separate each Data Model used for each TableViewCell in a different section like this:

```
if (indexPath.section == 0) {
//Each CollectionViewCell should display Profile Picture of User
} else if (indexPath.section == 1) {
//Each CollectionViewCell should display Pictures uploaded in this group
}
```

I am using the TableViewCell provided by Ash Furrow: http://ashfurrow.com/blog/putting-a-uicollectionview-in-a-uitableviewcell

I want to achieve the same results as this guy: [multiple UICollectionviews inside a UItabelview with sections - swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28125205/multiple-uicollectionviews-inside-a-uitabelview-with-sections-swift/28127622#28127622)
but I have quite a different code and his is written in swift, and I don't don't know to solve my problem by using the solution provided answer given by @pbasdf

Edit: These are the cells, I want the "Going" Cell to show Profile Pictures of the Users and the "Photos" Cell to show images uploaded to this group, but both cells are currently using the same data model and I don't know how to use different data models for each cell (the cells are divided by sections). [image]

Comment: Have you considered implementing CollectionView dataSource and Delegate inside your custom cell? Can you explain a bit more what are you trying to achieve and what is your problem

Comment: I have edited my question, hope you understand my problem now @NickCatib

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any implementation of a table view or a collection view should have a dedicated model.

Simply pass the model down.

NSArray > NSArray > Profile Pictures

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    CustomCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];
    NSArray *list = self.lists[indexPath.row];
    [cell configureWithList:list];
    return cell;
```

}

```
@interface CustomTableViewCell () <UICollectionViewDataSource>
@property (nonatomic, weak) NSArray *list;
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UICollectionView *collectionView;
@end

@implementation CustomTableViewCell

-(void)setList:(NSArray *)list {
    _list = list;
    [self.collectionView reloadData];
}

-(void)configureWithList:(NSArray *)list {
    self.list = list;
}
```

EDIT: After reading this, I decided to build this control -> [cocoacontrols](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/rrncollectiontableviewsections)

Comment: The only issue with that is that the table view cell now has access to the model, breaking MVC. By directing the collection view datasource callbacks back to the controller, we maintain a separation of concerns.

Comment: "The only issue with that is that the table view cell now has access to the model, breaking MVC." Views must have access to a model (this is MVC). If you deem it necessary (which I personally don't), then do this [tableViewCell.contentView addSubview:collectionViewController.view], making sure you set the parentViewController connection in cellForRow.

Comment: Updated my answer again Ash Furrow

Answer (score 1):

Sounds a bit tricky, but I think it should be possible without too much work.

You would need to tell the table view how many sections you have, and change `numberOfItemsInSection:` to return the number of rows in each respective section (looks like only one, based on your screenshot). Finally, we need to augment the `AFIndexedCollectionView` collection view subclass. Right now it stores an integer index, but we would need to modify it to store an index *path* instead. Then the collection view's `cellForItemAtIndexPath:` method would use that index path to determine which section the collection view is in.

It's a bit tricky, might make sense to draw the UI out on paper and reason about it that way. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks, It works when I implement it in your xcode-project! However, when I try to implement it in my project, the cells are like using the same cell twice, I dont know how to explain that. I'm using Interfacebuilder btw.